# Android Firestore filter recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I developed a "rent-a-car" android application in Android Studio(Java) and I want to add a new feature to it. I want to add to the home page, where all the available cars are displayed a button which opens a new activity where the user can filter by multiple criterias what cars to be displayed to him (from the recyclerview). For example: he can choose fuel type, number of seats, traction type etc.

My question is: how can I pass data from FilterCars activity(where users filter cars) to HomeFragment (where all the cars are displayed)? Do I need a custom RecyclerView builder to be able to handle compound queries?

EDIT: Let's say I pass the filters from FilterCars.class to HomeFragment.class with intent bundles. But what to do in HomeFragment to apply these filters?

Right now FragmentCars.class is empty because I don't have an idea how to pass the filters to HomeFragment and how to handle them there. Here is HomeFragment.class code (where all the cars are displayed):

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
carAdapter adapter; // Create Object of the Adapter class
ImageButton btnSort;
private static ProgressBar progressBar;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
    Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Cars").orderBy("carName");
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBarHome);
    btnSort = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSort);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler1);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<car> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<car>()
            .setQuery(query, car.class)
            .build();

    btnSort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), FilterCars.class));  // Here we open the activity which contains all the filters
        }
    });

    adapter = new carAdapter(options);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}



public static void disableProgressBar() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();

}

// Function to tell the app to stop getting
// data from database on stoping of the activity
@Override public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate
It suppose to help you.

You can also learn about startActivityForResult() if you really wants to have filters as an Activity. Checkout :
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

I don't know how exactly you want to do it, because I don't know much about your app architecture and needs. Anyway,I hope those links will give you opportunities, which you are looking for.

Comment: I understood how to pass data between activities, my main concern is how to get all those filters, combine them into a query and then apply those queries to the FirestoreRecyclerOptions builder as the user selected. And how to design it so the user can leave some filters blank and the query to still work ( something like: if he choose fuel: diesel, seats: 5 but at traction he doesn't want to filter (or leave it default like traction : all or something like that). Did I make myself clear?

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java  Just use updateOptions. I can't help you to construct the query cause you didn't include any informations about how the table looks like. The key is just to have a disctiory or map <filterType, chosenFilters>. Than make a method, which will constrct the query from the map.

Comment: In other words - what kind of nodes have you got in the car?

Comment: Ok.. I have a collection called "Cars" which contains many documents with random generated ID. Each document represents a car and contains attributes like: carName, fuel, seats, gearBox, traction etc. If i filter those in FilterCars.class and I pass them to HomeFragment where all the cars are displayed, how can I make a compound query and then pass the query to FirestoreRecyclerOptions?  For example user choose in FilterCars the following: fuel: "Diesel" , traction :"AWD" and seats: 5 . Then I pass those informations to HomeFragment where I should make a query with those 3 criterias.

Comment: My suggestion is send your filters to Activity and get your data with that filter (at that Activity create compound query and use SnapshotListener inside onStart method).

Comment: I think that you are trying to do "select" query like in the relative database. But Firebase Realtime Database is in type of NoSQL database. Look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL   It is not that simple that the query will do the job. You need to desing the nodes correctly, if you want to use Query for filtering. Too be honest it would be better to just filter the items by yourself. Like this: https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/ It's just an example